# Creating training dataset with .mids object in R

Tags: r, training-data, r-mice

I have data with missing components, so I've run the mice algorithm (from package `mice`). The function returns a .mids object, which I want to split into a training and a test dataset to assess model fit. I want the training and test data to be of .mids form too so that they can be combined with various other functions such as `pool` to adjust standard errors according to Rubin's rules.

Here's my attempt where I simply remove rows from the data to get a training set:

```
library(mice)
data <- mice(nhanes,m=2,maxit=5,seed=1)

set.seed(2)
rand <- (1:nrow(nhanes))*rbinom(nrow(nhanes),size=1,prob=0.7)
train <- data
train$data <- train$data[rand,]
```

But then if I try to run a model with this data:

```
pool(with(train, lm(bmi ~ chl + age)))
```

I encounter an error stating that it's trying to replace 9 rows with 7 (presumably because I decreased the number of rows in train$data without adjusting other stuff as well).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to loop through the `complete` datasets and then assign the `mira` class to the list, which should allow `pool`ing. (which is really what `mice:::with.mids` does)

Example without sampling

```
library(mice)

imp <- mice(nhanes,m=2, maxit=5, seed=1)

# With in-built pooling
pool(with(imp, lm(bmi ~ chl + age)))

# Pooled coefficients:
# (Intercept)         chl         age 
# 21.38496144  0.05975537 -3.40773396 
# 
# Fraction of information about the coefficients missing due to nonresponse: 
# (Intercept)         chl         age 
#   0.6186312   0.1060668   0.7380962 

# looping manually
mod <- list(analyses=vector("list", imp$m))

for(i in 1:imp$m){
  mod$analyses[[i]] <- lm(bmi ~ chl + age, data=complete(imp, i))
}

class(mod) <- c("mira", "matrix")
pool(mod)

# Pooled coefficients:
# (Intercept)         chl         age 
# 21.38496144  0.05975537 -3.40773396 
# 
# Fraction of information about the coefficients missing due to nonresponse: 
# (Intercept)         chl         age 
#   0.6186312   0.1060668   0.7380962
```

Seems okay, so add in a sampling procedure

```
mod <- list(analyses=vector("list", imp$m))

set.seed(1)
for(i in 1:imp$m){
  rand <- (1:nrow(nhanes))*rbinom(nrow(nhanes),size=1,prob=0.7)
  mod$analyses[[i]] <- lm(bmi ~ chl + age, data=complete(imp, i)[rand,])
}

class(mod) <- c("mira", "matrix")
pool(mod)

# Pooled coefficients:
# (Intercept)         chl         age 
# 21.72382272  0.06468044 -4.23387415 
# 
# Fraction of information about the coefficients missing due to nonresponse: 
# (Intercept)         chl         age 
#   0.1496987   0.4497024   0.6101340
```